# NestJS: Raw SQL query execution with SQL Server too slow. Configuration problems?

Tags: sql-server, nestjs, query-optimization, nestjs-config

APP in Nestjs that is connected to a SQL Server database. All the queries are written on the database side, so the connection between them is with simple raw SQL and the use of `mssql` package.

Here is the thing: when I run in SSMS, a very small query (let's say returning < 20 records) is executed in milliseconds (even larger and complex queries or stored procedures have good performance).

When I run in the app, with a local database connection, queries start having some delay (let's say 1 second for the same query).

But when I start using the database on Azure, the same small query takes 3 to 5 seconds (for 20 records).

I read some of causes could be related to parameter sniffing, but I don't think it is the case.

What I guess, is that my backend is restarting the database connection every time a new query arrives.

Here is the logic of the app: one centralized CRUD service to be used by the controllers.

In `main.ts` is the connection:

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule);
  const logger = new Logger('Bootstrap', { timestamp: true });
  const configService = app.get(ConfigService);

  // Database configuration
  const sqlConfig = {
    user:
      configService.get('DB_USELOCAL') === 'false'
        ? configService.get('DB_USERNAME')
        : configService.get('DB_USERNAME_LOCAL'),
    password:
      configService.get('DB_USELOCAL') === 'false'
        ? configService.get('DB_PASSWORD')
        : configService.get('DB_PASSWORD_LOCAL'),
    server:
      configService.get('DB_USELOCAL') === 'false'
        ? configService.get('DB_SERVER')
        : configService.get('DB_SERVER_LOCAL'),
    database:
      configService.get('DB_USELOCAL') === 'false'
        ? configService.get('DB_DATABASE')
        : configService.get('DB_DATABASE_LOCAL'),
    pool: {
      max: 10,
      min: 0,
      idleTimeoutMillis: 30000,
    },
    requestTimeout: 180000, //3 minutes to wait for a request to the database.
    options: {
      // encrypt: false, // for azure
      encrypt: configService.get('DB_USELOCAL') === 'false' ? true : false,
      trustServerCertificate: false, // change to true for local dev / self-signed certs
    },
  };
  sql.connect(sqlConfig);
  logger.log('App connected to SQL Server database');

  // CORS: Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS) is a mechanism that allows resources to be requested from another domain.
  app.enableCors();

  // App running
  await app.listen(configService.get('PORT') || 3000);
  logger.log(`App running on port ${configService.get('PORT') || 3000}`);
}
bootstrap();
```

At the CRUD Service the queries requested

```
import { HttpException, HttpStatus, Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { fxSQLerrorMsg } from './function/SLQerrorMsg.fx';
import * as sql from 'mssql';
import { FxArrayObjectStr } from './function/arrayObjectStr.fx';
import { FxObjectStr } from './function/objectStr.fx';
import { FindBodyDTO } from './findBody.dto';

@Injectable()
export class CrudService {
  private logger = new Logger('Crud Service', { timestamp: true });

  async find(
    sp: string,
    DB: string,
    body?: FindBodyDTO | null,
    query?: Record<string, any> | null,
    email?: string,
    filter?: string,
  ): Promise<Record<string, any>[]> {
    const method = "'" + 'find' + "'";
    const storedProcedure =
      process.env.SPECIFYDB == 'true'
        ? 'EXECUTE [' + DB + '].[ml_sp].[' + sp + ']'
        : 'EXECUTE [ml_sp].[' + sp + ']';
    const bodyParam = body
      ? "'" + JSON.stringify(body).replace('%20', ' ') + "'"
      : null;
    const queryParam = FxObjectStr(query);
    const emailScript = email ? "'" + email + "'" : null;
    const filterScript = filter ? "'" + filter + "'" : null;
    const spScript =
      storedProcedure +
      ' ' +
      method +
      ', ' +
      bodyParam +
      ', ' +
      queryParam +
      ',' +
      emailScript +
      ',' +
      filterScript;
    this.logger.verbose(spScript);

    try {
      return (await sql.query<Record<string, any>[]>(spScript))
        .recordset as unknown as Record<string, any>[];
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(error);
      throw new HttpException(
        fxSQLerrorMsg(error.message, 'Find'),
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
  }

  async post(
    sp: string,
    DB: string,
    body: Record<string, any>[],
    email?: string,
    filter?: string,
  ): Promise<Record<string, string>> {
    const method = "'" + 'post' + "'";
    const storedProcedure =
      process.env.SPECIFYDB == 'true'
        ? 'EXECUTE [' + DB + '].[ml_sp].[' + sp + ']'
        : 'EXECUTE [ml_sp].[' + sp + ']';
    const bodyParam = FxArrayObjectStr(body);
    const queryParam = null;
    const emailScript = email ? "'" + email + "'" : null;
    const filterScript = filter ? "'" + filter + "'" : null;
    const spScript =
      storedProcedure +
      ' ' +
      method +
      ', ' +
      bodyParam +
      ', ' +
      queryParam +
      ', ' +
      emailScript +
      ',' +
      filterScript;
    this.logger.verbose(spScript);
    try {
      return (
        (await sql.query<string>(spScript)).recordset as any[]
      )[0] as Record<string, string>;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(error);
      throw new HttpException(
        fxSQLerrorMsg(error.message, 'Post'),
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
  }

  async updateOne(
    sp: string,
    DB: string,
    body: Record<string, any>[],
    query?: Record<string, any>,
    email?: string,
    filter?: string,
  ): Promise<Record<string, string>> {
    const method = "'" + 'updateOne' + "'";
    const storedProcedure =
      process.env.SPECIFYDB == 'true'
        ? 'EXECUTE [' + DB + '].[ml_sp].[' + sp + ']'
        : 'EXECUTE [ml_sp].[' + sp + ']';
    const bodyParam = FxArrayObjectStr(body);
    const queryParam = FxObjectStr(query);
    const emailScript = email ? "'" + email + "'" : null;
    const filterScript = filter ? "'" + filter + "'" : null;
    const spScript =
      storedProcedure +
      ' ' +
      method +
      ', ' +
      bodyParam +
      ', ' +
      queryParam +
      ', ' +
      emailScript +
      ',' +
      filterScript;
    this.logger.verbose(spScript);
    try {
      return (
        (await sql.query<string>(spScript)).recordset as any[]
      )[0] as Record<string, string>;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(error);
      throw new HttpException(
        fxSQLerrorMsg(error.message, 'Update'),
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
  }

  async updateMany(
    sp: string,
    DB: string,
    body: Record<string, any>[],
    query?: Record<string, any>,
    email?: string,
    filter?: string,
  ): Promise<Record<string, string>> {
    const method = "'" + 'updateMany' + "'";
    const storedProcedure =
      process.env.SPECIFYDB == 'true'
        ? 'EXECUTE [' + DB + '].[ml_sp].[' + sp + ']'
        : 'EXECUTE [ml_sp].[' + sp + ']';
    const bodyParam = FxArrayObjectStr(body);
    const queryParam = FxObjectStr(query);
    const emailScript = email ? "'" + email + "'" : null;
    const filterScript = filter ? "'" + filter + "'" : null;
    const spScript =
      storedProcedure +
      ' ' +
      method +
      ', ' +
      bodyParam +
      ', ' +
      queryParam +
      ', ' +
      emailScript +
      ',' +
      filterScript;
    this.logger.verbose(spScript);
    try {
      return (
        (await sql.query<string>(spScript)).recordset as any[]
      )[0] as Record<string, string>;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(error);
      throw new HttpException(
        fxSQLerrorMsg(error.message, 'Update'),
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
  }

  async deleteOne(
    sp: string,
    DB: string,
    query?: Record<string, any>,
    email?: string,
    filter?: string,
  ): Promise<Record<string, string>> {
    const method = "'" + 'deleteOne' + "'";
    const storedProcedure =
      process.env.SPECIFYDB == 'true'
        ? 'EXECUTE [' + DB + '].[ml_sp].[' + sp + ']'
        : 'EXECUTE [ml_sp].[' + sp + ']';
    const bodyParam = null;
    const queryParam = FxObjectStr(query);
    const emailScript = email ? "'" + email + "'" : null;
    const filterScript = filter ? "'" + filter + "'" : null;
    const spScript =
      storedProcedure +
      ' ' +
      method +
      ', ' +
      bodyParam +
      ', ' +
      queryParam +
      ', ' +
      emailScript +
      ',' +
      filterScript;
    this.logger.verbose(spScript);
    try {
      return (
        (await sql.query<string>(spScript)).recordset as any[]
      )[0] as Record<string, string>;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(error);
      throw new HttpException(
        fxSQLerrorMsg(error.message, 'Delete'),
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
  }

  async deleteMany(
    sp: string,
    DB: string,
    body: Record<string, any>[],
    query: Record<string, any>,
    email?: string,
    filter?: string,
  ): Promise<Record<string, string>> {
    const method = "'" + 'deleteMany' + "'";
    const storedProcedure =
      process.env.SPECIFYDB == 'true'
        ? 'EXECUTE [' + DB + '].[ml_sp].[' + sp + ']'
        : 'EXECUTE [ml_sp].[' + sp + ']';
    const bodyParam = FxArrayObjectStr(body);
    const queryParam = FxObjectStr(query);
    const emailScript = email ? "'" + email + "'" : null;
    const filterScript = filter ? "'" + filter + "'" : null;
    const spScript =
      storedProcedure +
      ' ' +
      method +
      ', ' +
      bodyParam +
      ', ' +
      queryParam +
      ', ' +
      emailScript +
      ',' +
      filterScript;
    this.logger.verbose(spScript);
    try {
      return (
        (await sql.query<string>(spScript)).recordset as any[]
      )[0] as Record<string, string>;
    } catch (error) {
      this.logger.error(error);
      throw new HttpException(
        fxSQLerrorMsg(error.message, 'Delete'),
        HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST,
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Additional information: the query that I am testing (what I called a very small query) is:

```
ALTER VIEW [ml_view].[User2Role] AS 
(SELECT [ml_users].[User2Role].[id] as [id],
[User_user_Aux].[email] as [user],
[PortfolioRole_portfoliorole_Aux].[name] as [portfoliorole],
[ml_users].[User2Role].[editiondate] as [editiondate],
[User_editedbyuser_Aux].[email] as [editedbyuser] 
FROM [ml_users].[User2Role]
LEFT JOIN [ml_users].[User] as [User_user_Aux] ON [User_user_Aux].[id] = [ml_users].[User2Role].[userid] 
LEFT JOIN [ml_setup].[PortfolioRole] as [PortfolioRole_portfoliorole_Aux] ON [PortfolioRole_portfoliorole_Aux].[id] = [ml_users].[User2Role].[portfolioroleid] 
LEFT JOIN [ml_users].[User] as [User_editedbyuser_Aux] ON [User_editedbyuser_Aux].[id] = [ml_users].[User2Role].[editedbyuser])
```

Actually, it is stored as view, and run through a stored procedure. But we tested executing the view directly (`Select * from [viewName]`), and the result is the same.

Comment: Yes it could be parameter sniffing. But it could also just be plan-affecting `@@OPTIONS` values differing between SSMS and your application. Queries are planned and cached based on the combination of the hash of each statement along with the runtime `@@OPTIONS` values, so differing `@@OPTIONS` values can result in (very) different plans even with byte-for-byte identical statements. [Troubleshoot query performance difference between database application and SSMS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/troubleshoot-application-slow-ssms-fast).

Comment: It might be helpful if you [edit]ed your question to show us the actual SQL statements you send via `sql.query()`. And the code of the SPs involved.

Comment: Just added the query. Don't think the problem is that, it is a really simple view to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: the problem was not in the NestJS configuration to the SQL Server, was precisely in the resources assigned in Azure to the database (DTU or vCores)

I summarize next some of the actions that we undertook, but in the end, it was a silly mistake. However, guess is useful to keep the post.

- Data sniffing controlling.
- Rebuild index.
- Reset statistics.
- Trying different SQL configurations in Nestjs (typeorm, tedious, etc.)
- Assigned resources to the (DTU or Vcore model). See in Azure "Compute + Storage" section.